# systemd says "networking.service failed" but network is up

Tags: networking, systemd, network-interface, initramfs, init

Normally, I run Gentoo with openrc init, but am installing a Debian 10 server and having some trouble understanding systems. The server boots via a custom dracut initrd which created a bonded network interface and then boots from an iscsi root. That part all works fine. There are three interfaces which all come up on boot with their respective networks: 192.168.1.0/24, 10.0.0.0/24, and 172.16.0.0/24.

My (small) problem is systemd giving the following information:

```
# systemctl --failed
  UNIT               LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● networking.service loaded failed failed Raise network interfaces
```

I assume this largely due to one of the networks being active at init time. In Gentoo, I can mark an interface as not providing the network service. Does systemd have a similar concept or is there a setting that I've missed somewhere? Again, all interfaces are actually up and working appropriately (2 bridges, 1 bond) I've snipped local interfaces and the NICS in the bond and bridges.

```
 # ip addr list
[...]
7: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:6e:96:5e:a3:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.14/24 brd 172.16.0.255 scope global dynamic bond0
       valid_lft 249300sec preferred_lft 249300sec
    inet6 fe80::266e:96ff:fe5e:a39c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[...]
9: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:10:18:64:0f:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.14/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global vmbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::210:18ff:fe64:f3c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: vmbr1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:10:18:64:0f:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.14/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global vmbr1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::210:18ff:fe64:f3e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# ping -I vmbr0 -c 3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.1.14 vmbr0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=68.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=114 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=61.6 ms
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

[EDIT to additional information requested]

```
# systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-05-04 08:47:07 CDT; 4h 13min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
 Main PID: 1586 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 04 08:47:04 proxmox systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
May 04 08:47:04 proxmox ifup[1586]: Waiting for a max of 0 seconds for # no delay before a port becomes available to bec
May 04 08:47:05 proxmox ifup[1586]: Waiting for vmbr0 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 2 seconds).
May 04 08:47:06 proxmox ifup[1586]: Waiting for a max of 0 seconds for # no delay before a port becomes available to bec
May 04 08:47:07 proxmox ifup[1586]: Waiting for vmbr1 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 2 seconds).
May 04 08:47:07 proxmox ifup[1586]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 04 08:47:07 proxmox ifup[1586]: ifup: failed to bring up vmbr1
May 04 08:47:07 proxmox systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 08:47:07 proxmox systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 08:47:07 proxmox systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

and

```
# journalctl -u networking.service
-- Logs begin at Tue 2021-05-04 08:46:28 CDT, end at Tue 2021-05-04 12:17:01 CDT. --
May 04 08:47:04 proxmox systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
May 04 08:47:04 proxmox ifup[1586]: Waiting for a max of 0 seconds for # no delay before a port becomes available to bec
May 04 08:47:05 proxmox ifup[1586]: Waiting for vmbr0 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 2 seconds).
May 04 08:47:06 proxmox ifup[1586]: Waiting for a max of 0 seconds for # no delay before a port becomes available to bec
May 04 08:47:07 proxmox ifup[1586]: Waiting for vmbr1 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 2 seconds).
May 04 08:47:07 proxmox ifup[1586]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 04 08:47:07 proxmox ifup[1586]: ifup: failed to bring up vmbr1
May 04 08:47:07 proxmox systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 08:47:07 proxmox systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 08:47:07 proxmox systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

Comment: `sudo systemctl status networking.service` ? `sudo journalctl -u networking.service` ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I had two gateways defined in /etc/network/interfaces. Once I removed all but one, the error is corrected.

```
# systemctl --failed
0 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```